# Why are my integer values not being displayed or calculated correctly in C?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments, argv

By trade I'm a PHP programmer and wanted to test writing a C program, sending it arguments and using it's output in PHP using `shell_exec()`.

Anyway, I wrote this code simply to add two numbers together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int leftop, rightop, result;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    leftop = (int) argv[1];

    rightop = (int) argv[2];

    result = leftop + rightop;

    printf("The result of %i add %i = %i\n", leftop, rightop, result);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

i compile it with `MinGW` using `gcc -o main.c mycprogram.exe`.

When I run the program (either using `shell_exec()` (php) or from command line) I get the following results.

`./mycprogram.exe 25 25`

`The result of 7150824 add 7149184 = 14300008`

then i run it again and get:

`The result of 6692040 add 6692072 = 13384112`

obviously I expect the result to be `50`.

How come I'm not getting the correct results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, `argv[1]` (`argv[n]`, in general) is a pointer to a *string* cating that to `int` does not give you the corresponding integer which you might have passed as argument.

That said, the validity of the statement(s) like

```
 leftop = (int) argv[1];
```

are heavily implementation dependent, as validity of pointer-to-integer conversion is implementation specific behaviour. In some of the cases, it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:** You should be using [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to convert the *string* to integer type.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you possibly explain why casting to an int results in the values that I did get? just to help me understand what C is doing a bit more?

Comment: @AdamCopley Already updated the answer.

Comment: So was I effectively casting a memory address to an integer? hence the large numbers?

Comment: @AdamCopley Yep, right.

Comment: Aha Thanks again!